# Laravel 5 relationship between to belong

Tags: php, laravel, orm, relationship

I have a three table `vendor` `banquet` `project`,
and the relationship is like following description: 
* `vendor` hasMany `banquet` and `project`

```
class Vendor extends Model
{
   .....
  public function project()
  {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Project' ,'vendorId' ,'id');
  }

  public function banquet()
  {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Banquet' ,'vendorId' ,'id');
  }
}
```

*`banquet` belongsTo `vendor`

```
class Banquet extends Model
{
    ...
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Vendor' ,'vendorId' ,'id');
    }
}
```

*`project` belongsTo `vendor`

```
class Project extends Model
{
    ...
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entities\Vendor' ,'vendorId' ,'id');
    }
}
```

And some situation, I just have `banquet.id` that can find `banquet` data and 
at the same time, need to get all of the same vendorId `project` data within a query.

How can I defined the new relationship between `project` and `banquet`? or any idea can find the two kinds data in once query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as:

```
$banquet = Banquet::where('id', $banquet_id)->with('vendor.project')->first();
```

then get all of the same vendorId `project` data as:

```
$banquet->vendor->project;
```

it gives the collection of the project.

OR

You can use [`has-many-through`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation to access `project` from `banquet` model.

For this create a following function in `Banquet.php` class

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Entities\Project', 'App\Entities\Banquet');
}
```

then your query will be like:

```
$banquet = Banquet::where('id', $banquet_id)->with('project')->first();

$banquet->project;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!  but, is that any possible to get the Project likes `$banquet->project` ? `$banquet->vendor->project` seems too long